# Recupera imagem salva na memoria interna

Tags: android, memória, imagem

Estou salvando minha imagem na memoria interna usando este código

```
public String baixarImagem(String urlC, String nomeImagem) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL(urlC);

    InputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        String outputName = nomeImagem + ".jpg";

        input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        output = context.openFileOutput(outputName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int read;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = input.read(data)) != -1)
            output.write(data, 0, read);

        return outputName;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();

            if (input != null)
                input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

mais não sei recuperar essa imagem salva, nem mesmo sei se este código está salvando mesmo a imagem.
Alguém pode me falar se este código está certo e me mostrar como recuperar a imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça algo assim:

```
String path = context.getFilesDir().toString();
String fileName = "nome_imagem.jpg";

Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + fileName);
```

Com o `Bitmap` você pode exibir onde for necessário.